# How to hide untracked files in GitKraken's "Unstaged Files"?

Tags: linux, gitkraken

When current work in progress branch is selected, GitKraken shows two types of files: "Unstaged Files" and "Staged Files". Quite often there is a huge amount of files listed under "Unstaged", even only a few are really under source control; files are mostly untracked.

Is it possible to filter out the "untracked" files, and show only tracked (but modified) ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gitkraken's unstaged files area doesn't have a way to turn off untracked files completely, but it will respect your .gitignore. Create a file called `.gitignore` at the root of your repo, and add the names of files or folders you know you don't want to track. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Generally, the way most people use git is to gitignore ephemeral files, build artifacts, and configuration files, and commit everything else in the repo. If you have a large number of untracked files, you should probably gitignore them, or if you have some reason not to gitignore them, you might want to rethink your git strategy.